# forcing linux kernel 3 to recognize cdrom as hdX

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have a problem with older version of anaconda linux installer. I have upgraded kernel in my distro, however, when this anaconda boot with this 3.4.52 kernel, can NOT find cdrom. As far as I understand, this is because the new kernel recognize cd drive as srX, scdX instead of older hdX.
At the moment I can not upgrade anaconda and forced this kernel to recognize it as before.

Are there any kernel command line argument or something else for kernel 3.4.52 to recognize this cdrom as hdX?

Best Regards,

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: I am upgrading the kernel in my custom distro. Anaconda uses the kernel in the distro. With the kernel is upgraded, anaconda messages:
`[    1.634874] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
    [    1.636220] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
    ERROR: No CDROM devices found!
code`

For more information [http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.kickstart.general/9616/match=]

Answer (score 1):

Just make a symlink to your cdrom with the desired name. You can also make it automatically with udev, see: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.2/chapter07/symlinks.html

Comment: Actually I have tried lots of things. This is not as simple as a symlink. Anaconda C application find CDROM according to some info provided by kernel. Also, Anaconda stage1 has a very limited debug option.